# How to make the thumb of a slider move all the way to the end?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, rangeslider

Basically, I want a range slider that works well for true and false.

```css
fieldset > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.quiz-label-left, .quiz-label-right{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.quiz-slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.quiz-slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quiz-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<span class="quiz-label quiz-label-left">TRUE</span>
<input type="range" class="quiz-slider" name="quiz-slider" min="0" max="2" step="1" value="1">
<span class="quiz-label quiz-label-right">FALSE</span>
</fieldset>
```

The idea was to use 2 as true, 0 as false, and 1 as the default. The problem is, with such a small range, the thumb doesn't move very much. Ideally, I'd have the thumb move all the way to the end for either answer. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: After turning your code into a snippet, the slider clicks to either side immediately, what is the issue? Is ti caused by the fact you never opened your `<fieldset>` tag?

Comment: No, that's a bug in a me copy-pasting. Not sure what the issue is, then. :/

Comment: Hm, what behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: The thumb is moving a very tiny amount, as if it expects the range to be 100 or something.

Comment: Yeah, the code you supplied [works this way already](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/gOOqedd).

Comment: Sigh. It was a bug in my css. It was inheriting padding of 30 from another selector. Setting padding to 0 fixes it. -_- Man I hate CSS>

Comment: oof, consider answering your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, apparently what was happening was that the slider was inheriting a padding from a selector

```
.quiz-card * {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}
```

This was causing my thumb to have a tiny range in which to move. Setting the slider's padding to 0 fixed it.

```
.quiz-slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not for two days, apparently. Sorry guys.

Comment: Oh yeah, damn, SO is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-slider")[0].value = 2;
```

Id and tag name selectors also work.
here is the complete code:

```js
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-slider")[0].value = 2;
```

```css
 fieldset > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.quiz-label-left, .quiz-label-right{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.quiz-slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.quiz-slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quiz-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <fieldset>
      <span class="quiz-label quiz-label-left">TRUE</span>
      <input type="range" class="quiz-slider" name="quiz-slider" min="0" max="2" step="1" value="1">
      <span class="quiz-label quiz-label-right">FALSE</span>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the behavior different than the supplied code?

Comment: It moves the slider to the end;

Comment: After turning his code into a snippet, it does too. See [here](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/gOOqedd).

Comment: No, he said that 1 is the default, and your link seems to also use 1 as the default.

Comment: That wasn't the issue, per his comment above: "The thumb is moving a very tiny amount, as if it expects the range to be 100 or something."

Comment: He should've wrote that in the title of his question.

Comment: I'll agree, it was a bit vague.

Comment: I'll delete my answer if somebody else claims that it doesn't answer the question, and indeed, I don't either have the problem he mentioned.